# Printing hexadecimal string in python

Tags: python

I'm on x86, little-endian. 
So I got this data from a udp packet.

```
data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)

print(data)
```

gives something like `'\xfe\x15'`

which I understand to be the little-endian layout in memory.

The value should be represented as 
0x15fe

In C i do,

```
printf("%x", hexvalue);
```

and it gives me 0x15fe straightaway.

How do I get Python to print the hexadecimal value out properly?

Many thanks.

Comment: have you tried repr(data)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the bytestring to an int using [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html), like this:

```
>>> data = b'\xfe\x15'
>>> num, = struct.unpack('<h', data)
```

Here `<h` represents a little-endian 2-bytes signed integer. Use `<H` if your data is unsigned. Check out the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-strings) for more.

Then you can print it using `print(hex(num))` or similar:

```
>>> print(hex(num))
0x15fe
```

---

As a side note, remember that `sock.recvfrom(1024)` may return more or less than 2 bytes. Keep that into account when parsing.